# Login to external website with PHP then display in iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I am trying to create function that will allow a user to hit a button which will send through the login details to an external website and then display with page after login in an iframe. Anyone know the best way to do this, I currently have this code as I read the cURL function works but I'm not sure how to get this to bring back the iframe or how to link with the button to call the function, I am quite new to PHP etc so any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
$username="user"; 
$password="pass"; 
$initials="ABC";
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");    
$post = array(
    'userId' =>$username,
    'password' =>$password,
    'initials' =>$initials
              );

$post_data = http_build_query($post);
$ch = curl_init('https://www.example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);// This stores the cookie , you can use it later  if you have to make more request which  requires user to be loged in
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: By defining `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` u tell curl to buffer and return the response. The response then can be assigned into a var by doing `$res = curl_exec($ch)`. Now `$res` contains the (HTML) output for the request. U could output this html in div with a fixed width, height and overflow : auto instead of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a post to the login page to log the server in. But I guess you actually want the current user to log in to the website? Since the Curl request is being done from the server and not from the user, this isn’t going to work.

If you also control the other website, you can send some sort of hash code to this site via CURL, save this in the local DB, and send the user a link with the hash code in it. On the other server you can match this hash code to the one in the DB, and if they match, log the user in.